# Docker container not starting

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run [this docker example](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/python_web_app/). Yet it appears that I can't start my docker container.

```
sudo docker stop aff28c5dab3f
sudo docker start aff28c5dab3f
sudo docker ps
ID                  IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS

sudo docker ps -a
ID                  IMAGE                     COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
aff28c5dab3f        shykes/pybuilder:latest   /usr/local/bin/build   26 minutes ago      Exit 0
52200b5c58a6        shykes/pybuilder:latest   /usr/local/bin/build   10 hours ago        Exit 0
b59e84340a7c        ubuntu:12.04              echo hello             11 hours ago        Exit 0
5c1bd5bc53d6        ubuntu:12.04              echo hello             12 hours ago        Exit 0
```

and when I try to run 
`sudo docker attach aff28c5dab36`, I see `Impossible to attach to a stopped container, start it first`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot to attach to the container, and hence was getting the error. I ran `sudo docker attach aff28c5dab36` and now everything works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by *that step*?

Comment: `sudo docker attach aff28c5dab36`

Comment: `You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that when you run `docker attch` command, the `buildapp` command inside the container is already finished and the container is stopped automatically. If you run `docker attach` immediately after run the `buildapp` command, you'll see its output.